# How to upgrade token-2022 version from 0.6.0 to 0.9.0 for private node

Tags: token-2022

How to upgrade token-2022 version from 0.6.0 to 0.9.0 if I launch a private solana node?

I launch solana validator node v1.16.14 with [fetch-spl.sh](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/v1.16.14/fetch-spl.sh#L48). Then downlaod [spl_token_2022-0.9.0.so](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/releases/tag/token-2022-v0.9.0) and execute `solana program deploy --upgrade-authority "${OPERATOR_KEYPAIR}" --program-id "${TOKEN_2022}" --url "${VALIDATOR_HTTP_URL}" spl_token_2022-0.9.0.so`. I got Account `Error: Program's authority Some(11111111111111111111111111111111) does not match authority provided 9SrdsYwr9GTjxNUSJpp4JzNv5NTpV4zHwzZo7hFGnrhQ`

If i try to launch a new chain with changed authority [fetch-spl.sh#20](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/v1.16.14/fetch-spl.sh#L20) to my pubkey `genesis_args+=(--upgradeable-program "$address" "$loader" "$so" 9SrdsYwr9GTjxNUSJpp4JzNv5NTpV4zHwzZo7hFGnrhQ)`. I will get `Error: Deploying program failed: Error processing Instruction 0: account data too small for instruction` if i execute solana program deploy.[image]

And the other question is how to upgrade token-2022 when chain launch with solana v1.14.x. [fetch-spl.sh](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/v1.14.19/fetch-spl.sh#L17) of Solana v1.14.x without --upgradeable-program parameter. I got `Error: TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb is not an upgradeable program` when I try to upgrade it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of questions here, so to separate them out:

The `account data too small for instruction` error probably comes from trying to deploy a larger program than the default one provided. The genesis args doesn't overallocate the buffer, which we could certainly fix.

In the meantime, if you want to deploy the new version of token-2022, rather than launching the network and then upgrading, you're better off directly putting in the program that you want to use.

Regarding the other issue on v1.14, the genesis program just defaulted to the non-upgradeable loader back then, so it's impossible to upgrade any program added that way. You can also just change the `.so` to fix that issue.